# Count distinct per month/year but display all dates in the query result

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, window-functions

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=33652121efafbceca135bf7a21f69803)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    orderID VARCHAR(255),
    sent_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO sales
(orderID, sent_date
)
VALUES 
("Order_01", "2019-03-15"),
("Order_01", "2019-03-16"),
("Order_02", "2020-06-16"),
("Order_03", "2020-07-27"),
("Order_03", "2020-08-05"),
("Order_03", "2020-08-10");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
sent_date      COUNT(distinct orderID)
2019-03-15              1
2019-03-16              0
2020-06-16              1
2020-07-27              1
2020-08-05              1
2020-08-10              0
```

---

In the above table I have the same `orders` with multiple `sent_dates`.

Now, I want to count the **unique** `orderIDs` per `month/year` on a **daily-basis**. 
Therefore, I am looking for a query that checks for each `orderID` if it already exists at a previous `sent_date` and if so the value for the current `sent_date` should be `0`.

I know the most simple way to the unique count per month/year would be this query:

```
SELECT
YEAR(sent_date),
MONTH(sent_date),
COUNT(distinct orderID)
FROM sales
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

However, I need to have each `sent_date` displayed seperately in a list as you can see in the expected result. 
What query do I need to get the **count unique** although I need to query the data on a **daily-basis**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want to a histogram of the first monthly occurence of each orderid per date.

Here is an approach using window functions, available in MySQL 8.0:

```
select sent_date, sum(rn = 1) cnt_distinct_orderid
from (
    select s.*, row_number() over(partition by year(sent_date), month(sent_date), orderid order by sent_date) rn
    from sales s
) t
group by sent_date
order by sent_date
```

In earlier versions, one option uses a self-join:

```
select d.sent_date, count(s.orderid) cnt_distinct_orderid
from (select distinct sent_date from sales) d
left join (
    select orderid, min(sent_date) min_sent_date
    from sales 
    group by orderid, date_format(sent_date, '%Y-%m-01')
) s on d.sent_date = s.min_sent_date
group by d.sent_date
```

**[Demon on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dcfa9fcb1c220cb4f1a236eae1d76033)**:

```
sent_date  | cnt_distinct_orderid
:--------- | -------------------:
2019-03-15 |                    1
2019-03-16 |                    0
2020-06-16 |                    1
2020-07-27 |                    1
2020-08-05 |                    1
2020-08-10 |                    0
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=623d964406b8175f9721c4e33465fba0

Comment: Just for my documenation. Using the SQL for daily import: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0f559794e87bc43cdc26569d3fba58c5

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to flag the first occurrence of each order in a month.  You can use window functions:

```
select s.*,
       ( row_number() over (partition by extract(year_month from sent_date), orderid order by sent_date) = 1 ) as flag
from s;
```

Window functions are supported in MySQL 8+.